# Opentok Archiving not working

Tags: php, wordpress, opentok, tokbox

I tried the sample archiving in opentok library and it was working fine. But when i tried it in my website in localhost or in server, i always get this error:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Guzzle\Http\Exception\ClientErrorResponseException' with message 'Client error response
[status code] 404
[reason phrase] Not Found
[url] https://api.opentok.com/v2/partner/44968642/archive' in /var/www/shabetaro/wp-content/themes/chico-child/library/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Exception/BadResponseException.php:43
Stack trace:

#0 /var/www/shabetaro/wp-content/themes/chico-child/library/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Message/Request.php(145): Guzzle\Http\Exception\BadResponseException::factory(Object(Guzzle\Http\Message\EntityEnclosingRequest), Object(Guzzle\Http\Message\Response))

#1 [internal function]: Guzzle\Http\Message\Request::onRequestError(Object(Guzzle\Common\Event), 'request.error', Object(Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher))

#2 /var/www/shabetaro/wp-content/themes/chico-child/library/symfony/event-dispatcher/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(164): call_user_func(Array, Object(Guzzle\Common\Event), 'request.error', Object(Symfony\Component\Eve in /var/www/shabetaro/wp-content/themes/chico-child/library/opentok/opentok/src/OpenTok/Util/Client.php on line 200

Code:

JQUERY

```
$.ajax({
    url: ggeajax.ajaxurl,
    data: {
        'action': 'gge_start_archive',
        'api'   : api
    }
});
```

PHP

```
function gge_start_archive()
{
    $api = $_REQUEST['api'];
    $opentok = getInstance('Helper_Opentok');
    gge_log("Starting archive", array('sessionID' => "Archive"));

    $archiveID = $opentok->start_archive($api['sessionID'], "Archive");
    die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_gge_start_archive', 'gge_start_archive');
```

OPENTOK

```
use OpenTok\OpenTok;
use OpenTok\Session;
use OpenTok\Role;
use OpenTok\MediaMode;

class Helper_Opentok {

public function initialize()
{
    $option = get_option('chico_settings');
    return new OpenTok($option['opentok_api'], $option['opentok_token']);
}

public function start_archive($sessionId, $name)
{
    $opentok = $this->initialize();
    $archiveId = $opentok->startArchive($sessionId, $name);
    gge_log("Generate archiveId", array('archiveId' => $archiveId, 'name' => $name, 'user' => get_userdata(get_current_user_id())));
    return $archiveId;
}
}
```

Comment: There could be many causes for this particular error. The most common is that you attempted to call `$opentok->startArchive($sessionId, $name)` before any clients connected to the session. In order for me to be more helpful, please provide some of the code you ran where this error occurred.

Comment: Thank you so much @Ankur. I will edit my question and provide the codes.

Comment: is the JQuery code running sometime after the "sessionConnected" event?

Comment: Hello @Ankur, I did it. You are right. I didn't notice that i was calling startArchive before clients are connected to the session. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hello @Taiga, I am also trying to archive video but I always get bool(false). I have asked same question but I think I had not asked my question properly. Can you share your code or you can answer my question from [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25887962/opentok-archiving-not-working). I will be glad.